# Socket.io on Heroku: client-side code

Tags: node.js, heroku, client-side, socket.io

I've been having trouble loading the socket.io library for my JS client code on a Node.js app hosted on Heroku.

For now, I have this line at the end of my index.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

But then, when I do `socket = io.connect('http://myherokuapp');`in my JS client code, I get an expected 'io is not defined' error.

Any idea how to correctly load the library on Heroku?

Thanks!

Comment: ok so I finally tried to push the client-side library "manually" with the rest of my app. It seems to work but now I run in a new problem during the initialization of socket.io.js : http://myherokuapp/socket.io/1/?t=1320939716103&jsonp=0 is called at some point and returns 404 no Object found.

Answer (score 10):

Ok so I finally found my way through. I'm sharing in case it helps someone.

I load the script in index.html this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myapp.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

It makes sense because the client-side library is actually loaded from the node server and shouldn't be pushed manually.

In my client-side JS file, I instantiate the socket this way:

```
socket = io.connect('http://myapp.herokuapp.com/');
```

Also, and this goes beyond the scope of this question, but you can't use websocket on Heroku for now. They have a little note about that [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku).

Hope this helps!

Comment: After changing code to this, is your App working at Heroku server? I am also facing the same issue and have not solved yet. I get the socket.io.js not found 404 error. I will try your code later today. Is your App working at Heroku server? Can you share the URL if its working?